# Exclude pattern of all .js files in IntelliJ when find usages

Tags: intellij-idea

I want to find all the usages of an object, and I'm getting a lot of transpiled .js files that I want to ignore. Using find in files option there is a mask we can add like this:

[image]

But in the find usages there isn't a mask.
I guess we can create a scope, but for some reason when I insert `!*.js` I'm still getting .js files.
[image]

What am I missing out?

Comment: A regex that matches a string not ending with `.js` is `^(?!.*\.js$).*`

Comment: Don't know why marked as a duplicate, intellij scope patterns has [rules](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html#options).
Anyway, solved my issue by `!file:*.js*`.

Comment: It is not a regex.